# Varying Vagrant Vagrants provision script issue

Tags: bash, shell, vagrant, vvv-wordpress

I'm trying to write a provision script for [Browscap](https://browscap.org/), and I'm almost there, I just want to see what I'm doing wrong when trying to rewrite `php.ini` file.

The repo is [here](https://github.com/dingo-d/browscap-vvv-utility).

The provision script looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Prettyfiers
BLUE='\033[0;36m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

DIR=`dirname $0`

echo "${BLUE}Setting up Browsecap${NC}"

# Check PHP version
PHP_VER=`php -r \@phpinfo\(\)\; | grep 'PHP Version' -m 1 | grep -Po -m 1 '(\d+\.\d+)' | head -1`
MIN_REQ="5.3"

if (( $(echo "${PHP_VER} < ${MIN_REQ}" |bc -l) )); then
  echo "${BLUE}The PHP version is lower than 5.3 so browscap won't work. Please upgrade your PHP version to higher than 5.3${NC}"
  exit 0
fi
echo "${BLUE}PHP version is${NC}" ${PHP_VER}

BROWSE_INI="/etc/php/${PHP_VER}/mods-available/php_browscap.ini"

# Check if browscap is already installed/set up
if [[ -f "${BROWSE_INI}" ]]; then
  echo "${BLUE}Browscap is already installed${NC}"
else
  # Set the browscap.ini and the php extension
  touch "${BROWSE_INI}"
  cp "php_browscap.ini" "${BROWSE_INI}"
  echo "${BLUE}Browscap copied${NC}"
fi

PHP_INI="/etc/php/${PHP_VER}/fpm/php.ini"

# Check if php.ini exists before replacing
if [[ -f "${PHP_INI}" ]]; then
  echo "${BLUE}php.ini exists${NC}"
  # Check if the default value exists - by default it should be ;browscap = extra/browscap.ini
  # If it doesn't then find browscap = and replace it with the correct one
  if [ "$(grep -qe ";browscap" "${PHP_INI}")" ]; then
    sudo sed -i "s|;browscap =|browscap = /etc/php/${PHP_VER}/mods-available/php_browscap.ini|g" "/etc/php/${PHP_VER}/fpm/php.ini"
  else
    sudo sed -i "s|browscap =|browscap = /etc/php/${PHP_VER}/mods-available/php_browscap.ini|g" "/etc/php/${PHP_VER}/fpm/php.ini"
  fi
  echo "${BLUE}php.ini changed${NC}"
else
  echo "${BLUE}php.ini doesn't exist${NC}"
fi
```

When the provision ends and I check my `php.ini` I get

```
[browscap]
; http://php.net/browscap
;browscap = /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/php_browscap.ini /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/php_browscap.ini extra/browscap.ini
```

So I'm missing something in my `sed` command.

But what?

## MVE

If you have VVV installed you can go to shh with `vagrant ssh`

Then go to `/home/vagrant` and create `text.txt` and `test.sh`

`text.txt`

```
[browscap]
;browscap = extra/browscap.ini
```

`test.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TEST_FILE="/home/vagrant/text.txt"

# Check if php.ini exists before replacing
if [[ -f "${TEST_FILE}" ]]; then
  echo "text.txt exists"
  # Check if the default value exists - by default it should be ;browscap = extra/browscap.ini
  # If it doesn't then find browscap = and replace it with the correct one
  if grep -q ";browscap" "${TEST_FILE}"; then
    sudo sed -i "s|;browscap =|browscap = /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/php_browscap.ini|g" "${TEST_FILE}"
  else
    sudo sed -i "s|browscap =|browscap = /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/php_browscap.ini|g" "${TEST_FILE}"
  fi
  echo "text.txt changed"
else
  echo "text.txt doesn't exist"
fi
```

This will result in `text.txt`

```
[browscap]
browscap = /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/php_browscap.ini extra/browscap.ini
```

Comment: [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output and a **minimal** script that demonstrates your specific problem (e.g. if you have a problem with a sed script then post the sed script, don't post a shell script that has the sed script buried inside it).

Comment: Ok, then I'll remove sed tag. This is the complete example of the shell script, and the instructions how to run it are given in the repo :)

Comment: We all have limited time to spend on any given question. If you post a minimal script with clear input/output then many people will try to help you. If you post a larger script with no input/output and expect people to go clicking around external web sites for more information then YMMV. Good luck!

Comment: I added MVE, should be easier now to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite this statement

```
if [ "$(grep -qe ";browscap" "${PHP_INI}")" ]; then
```

to just

```
if grep -q ";browscap" "${PHP_INI}"; then
```

since you can directly use `grep`'s return code in shell conditionals. The reason being in the former case, you are incorrectly checking the return code of `grep` to see if it succeeded, because the exit code is processed by the shell.

(or) alternatively you could also do

```
grep -qe ";browscap" "${PHP_INI}"
rc=$?  

if [ $rc -eq 0 ]; then
    echo 'match found'
fi
```

because `grep` returns a different exit code if its found something (zero) vs. if it hasn't found something (non-zero). In an if statement, a zero exit code is mapped to "true" and a non-zero exit code is mapped to false.

Also your `sed` statement should include the matching part after `=` which needs to be done as

```
sed -i "s|;browscap =.*|browscap = /etc/php/${PHP_VER}/mods-available/php_browscap.ini|g" "/etc/php/${PHP_VER}/fpm/php.ini"
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the MCVE you posted, you should replace this block of code:

```
if grep -q ";browscap" "${TEST_FILE}"; then
  sudo sed -i "s|;browscap =|browscap = /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/php_browscap.ini|g" "${TEST_FILE}"
else
  sudo sed -i "s|browscap =|browscap = /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/php_browscap.ini|g" "${TEST_FILE}"
fi
```

with just 1 line:

```
sudo sed -i 's|;?browscap =.*|browscap = /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/php_browscap.ini|' "${TEST_FILE}"
```

Comment: I did that, and I can swear I added this as a comment on Inian's answer :S